# jQuery Mobile: Jumping back to position in list-view (iOS 4.3)

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, ios4

I'm building an iPhone-app with Phonegap and jQuery Mobile. I have a list-view with multiple entries, linking to a detail-site for every entry.

With iOS > 4.3, when i navigate back from detail-page to list-view, i get back to the old position, where the entry was choosen. With iOS 4.3 that doesn't works.

(I also had a problem with fixed haeder and iOS 4.3 but solved it with the polyfill fix)

Is there a workaround for this problem too?

Thank you!